# Вывод полученных данных с помощью API в <i>

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

есть небольшая API под названием samp-query которая позволяет мониторить сервера и получать информацию о них, ниже пример кода, мне необходимо вывести полученную информацию об онлайне в

```
    var query = require('samp-query')

var options = {
    host: '94.23.166.205'
}

query(options, function (error, response) {
    if(error)
        console.log(error)
    else 
        console.log(response)
})
```

ВЫВОД

```
    { 
    address: '94.23.166.205',
    hostname: '• German Extreme Freeroam • Stunt/Derby/Race/DM/Free',
    gamemode: 'Stunt Race Derby DM Fun',
    mapname: 'San Andreas',
    passworded: false,
    maxplayers: 500,
    online: 12,
    rules: { 
        lagcomp: true,
        mapname: 'San Andreas',
        version: '0.3z',
        weather: 18,
        weburl: 'www.gef.io',
        worldtime: '12:00'
    },
    players: [
        { id: 0, name: 'hallihallomine', score: 14735, ping: 51 },
        { id: 1, name: 'xGreenDayx', score: 26193, ping: 81 },
        { id: 2, name: '[Black]Rider', score: 87211, ping: 41 },
        { id: 3, name: 'Kohl', score: 439313, ping: 45 },
        { id: 5, name: 'TheSituation', score: 14775, ping: 41 },
        { id: 6, name: 'EziT', score: 38914, ping: 66 },
        { id: 7, name: 'Josiee', score: 2104, ping: 56 },
        { id: 8, name: 'Derbystar', score: 29, ping: 56 },
        { id: 9, name: 'xXProPlayXx', score: 20354, ping: 45 },
        { id: 10, name: 'hakco30', score: 0, ping: 81 },
        { id: 11, name: 'xXDarkBolleXx', score: 38886, ping: 56 },
        { id: 12, name: 'SDMPro', score: 0, ping: 51 }
    ]
}
```

i

```
<i class="online-sff" aria-hidden="true">N/A</i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ответ в формате json? если да то [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Если вы это с консоли скопировали то скорее всего это и есть объект, онлайн можно получить с помощью доступа к параметру: response.online;
а вставить текст можно вот так:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("online-sff")[0].innerHTML = response.online;
```